# PHP mail doesn't require a password?

Tags: php, email, passwords

I got my mail script to work properly but I don't understand why PHP mail doesn't require me to enter the password for the **from** address.

Isn't it this dangerous? Couldn't someone use someone else's email to send inappropriate messages?

The mail script I used:

```
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

In other words: lets say if the I put your email address as the value of $from, that will send emails under your address.

Comment: Headers can be spoofable. How else do you think scammers make their emails look like they come from your bank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Couldn't someone use someone else's email to send inappropriate messages?

Yes. If you check your spam filter, you'll see lots and lots of these - messages that appear to be from major companies, government institutions, etc.

The way to prevent this is not a password, but proper SPF and DKIM records in your domain name's DNS settings.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out SPF and DKIM. To be honest I never heard of those, will look into it.

Comment: You should read http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Comment: Interesting article! Still reading it :P. Thanks for the link! Instant bookmark.